# django admin forms. how to skip validation?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have some form:

```
class Node(Object):
    title = CharField(max_length=255)
    body = TextField()
```

in admin form there is file field (which is a dump,for example csv dump of Nodes)

and what i want to do:
if user fills "data_file" i want to skip all form validation, and  create Nodes from data_file content. Otherwise i'll create Node based on "title" and "body fields"
I need help because can not find anything about my problem in django docs

There is method to create a url view, but i want to do it by django standart admin tools

Comment: Where is `data_file` defined? Why is `Node` inheriting from `Object`? Also note, the Django Admin app is designed for a specific purpose; creating your own view will be easier and have no weird hacks to make it work.

Comment: @EvanPorter, 
>>Why is Node inheriting from Object?
that's my mistake, it inherits django.db.models
I desided to create my own view

Comment: Django is OSS so when the doc doesn't answer your questions you can just read the code to find out...